# Converting a Maytag 4 prong dryer cord to 3 prong

Tags: electrical, dryer, appliances

[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

I have a Maytag dryer with a 4 prong set up and need to convert to a 3 prong outlet.  I haven’t been able to find this exact set up and need to know if the metal strap serves as a ground or if I need to add a jumper to the ground screw.

The picture included shows the 3 prong cable I’ve already installed.  The arrows point out the metal strap that was on the dryer with the 4 prong.

Comment: Turn off the breaker, pull the receptacle, and be absolutely sure there isn't a ground wire already there (there often is, surprisingly) **before** choosing to do the unsafe thing with your dryer. If it's really missing, consider upgrading the receptacle rather than downgrading the dryer.

Comment: model number of the dryer should lead to an exact diagram/instructions.

Comment: Yeah, they banned 3-wire outlets in 1996 *for a reason*.  The worst was several incidents when children dropped something behind the dryer, squeezed in between dryer and wall to go get it, touching both dryer frame and something grounded, *and no possibility of escape*. Imagine the parents finding their child that way.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the inside of the box for your dryer receptacle?

Answer (score 5):

#### DON'T DO THIS (unless)

The proper thing to do (full disclosure...I should have done this myself *years* ago but only got to it recently, but it is done!) is to replace the obsolete NEMA 10-30 3-wire receptacle with a current NEMA 14-30 4-wire receptacle.

As noted in a comment, the first step is to take apart the receptacle and see if you have a ground wire available. Unless it is a metal box connected via metal conduit all the way to the panel, in which case the conduit provides a valid ground path.

If you do *not* have a ground wire (or metal conduit), then it is still possible to do this properly by either replacing the cable or adding a separate ground wire.

Only if this is not practical, which means either:

- No existing ground wire
- No metal conduit
- Long or complicated path for running a new cable or ground wire

or

- Rental and unable to get landlord to bring in an electrician to replace the receptacle (because this can be DIY if you own, but not if you rent)

should you use a 3-wire cord/plug and an existing NEMA 10-30 receptacle, and in that case, yes the strap already in place appears to serve the purpose of ground/neutral bond. Speaking of which:

If you use a 4-wire plug/cord and NEMA 14-30 receptacle, you need to make sure that you do *not* have a ground/neutral bond in the dryer.

If you use (due to extreme circumstances) a 3-wire plug/cord and NEMA 10-30 receptacle, you to make sure that you *do* have ground/neutral bond in the dryer.

In either case, the way to be 100% certain is to use a multimeter.

- 4-wire

Test continuity at the plug. Without plugging in to the receptacle, check continuity between each pair of prongs on the plug attached to the cord attached to the dryer. (That sounds redundant, but I want to make sure you are checking the actual cord/plug and *not* the receptacle.) You should not have continuity between *any* pair on a 4-prong plug. If you do have continuity then the bond is still in place and must be removed.

- 3-wire

Check continuity between the neutral prong and bare metal on the dryer - if not continuous then the required bond is missing and must be added.